# Can't fill in a text input in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a text input that I want to fill in with the output of a function, however I don't know why It doesn't work ?

Here is my html code:

```
   <input type="text" min="0" ng-model="Resqty" size="10" required >
```

In angularJS I do:

```
      $scope.Resqty = $scope.total($scope.out);
      $scope.total = function total(out) {
         return data.convert($scope.qty, $scope.in, out);
      };
```

I also tried to put function directly as follows but it doesn't work neither:

```
      $scope.Resqty = data.convert($scope.qty, $scope.in, $scope.out);
```

However, in the html code when I put {{total(out)}} it works !
I also tried to put a value directly to verify and it worked !!

```
      $scope.Resqty = 1;
```

Does anyone know why the text input doesn't get the value correctly ?
Here is a link for a [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/IaFzueTrYdX2ygLzeyAW?p=preview)

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Is it a async function by any chance?

Comment: You want the prefilled textbox?

Comment: can you give me a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$scope.formData = { Resqty: null };

$scope.formData.Resqty = $scope.total($scope.out);
```

view:

```
<input type="text" min="0" ng-model="formData.Resqty" size="10" required >
```

By the way, your function isn't syntaxically correct:

```
// 2 times total, take out the second
$scope.total = function total(out) {
```

Comment: Thank you for your rapid response, however, it doesn't work I don't know why ? I updated my question for a Plunker link

Answer (score 0):

Wow!  There were so much errors in your code, as you have referred to your controller, as you put your directives you can see all this to update it and working as you want:

### js:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('invoice1', [])
    .controller('InvoiceController', function($scope) { // <---here you missed the $scope in the controller
      $scope.qty = 1; // <---now here on you need to replace all your 'this' to $scope
      $scope.cost = 2;
      $scope.inCurr = 'EUR';
      $scope.currencies = ['USD', 'EUR', 'CNY'];

      $scope.usdToForeignRates = {
        USD: 1,
        EUR: 0.74,
        CNY: 6.09
      };

      $scope.total = function(outCurr) {
        return $scope.convertCurrency($scope.qty * $scope.cost, $scope.inCurr, outCurr);
      };
      $scope.convertCurrency = function(amount, inCurr, outCurr) {
        return amount * $scope.usdToForeignRates[outCurr] / $scope.usdToForeignRates[inCurr];
      };
      $scope.pay = function() {
        window.alert("Thanks!");
      };
      $scope.Resqty = $scope.total($scope.inCurr);
    });
})(angular);
```

### Now your markup:

```
<div ng-app="invoice1" ng-controller="InvoiceController as invoice">
  <b>Invoice:</b>
  <div>
    Quantity:
    <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="qty" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    Costs:
    <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="cost" required>
    <select ng-model="inCurr">
      <option ng-repeat="c in currencies">{{c}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <b>Total:</b>
    <span ng-repeat="c in currencies">
      {{total(c) | currency:c}}
    </span>
    <input type="text" min="0" value="{{Resqty}}" size="10" required>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="pay()">Pay</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [Check this if you want something like.](http://plnkr.co/edit/bd2C9kdD5SjT9AaJnaCQ?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your response, in fact in your code the problem is that the "Resqty" text input doesn't update when the inCurr variable changes !

Comment: Here is an example of what I've tried but it doesn't work neither: http://plnkr.co/edit/hjS20eo4jQRTHx0ZLmS1?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** This line ***$scope.Resqty =  $scope.total(inCurr);*** will always give you the error function not defined as when you called this ***$scope.Resqty*** it won't pass any parameter to the function and so this is not being called. You can replicate this by not passing the parameter to the function:

In this way:

```
$scope.Resqty =  $scope.total();
//Also no parameter in this function
 $scope.total = function() {
 //return $scope.convertCurrency($scope.qty * $scope.cost, $scope.inCurr, outCurr);
};
```

This code works fine now...

```
<body >
 <div ng-app="invoice1" ng-controller="InvoiceController as invoice">
 <b>Invoice:</b>
 <div>
Quantity: <input type="text" min="0" ng-model="qty" required >
</div>

<div>
Costs: <input type="text" min="0" ng-model="cost" required >

<select ng-model="inCurr">

<option ng-repeat="c in currencies">{{c}}</option>
</select>
</div>

<div>  
  Res: <input type="text" min="0" required value={{total(outCurr)}}>
 <select ng-model="outCurr">

 <option ng-repeat="c in currencies">{{c}}</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
  <b>Total:</b>

<span ng-repeat="c in currencies">

 {{total(c) | currency:c}}
  </span>
  <button class="btn" ng-click="pay()">Pay</button>
  </div>

 </div>
 </body>
```

JS CODE:

```
 (function(angular) {
 'use strict';
  angular.module('invoice1', [])
 .controller('InvoiceController', function($scope) {
  $scope.qty = 1;
  $scope.cost = 2;
  $scope.inCurr = 'EUR';
  $scope.outCurr = 'EUR';
  $scope.currencies = ['USD', 'EUR', 'CNY'];

  $scope.usdToForeignRates = {
    USD: 1,
    EUR: 0.74,
    CNY: 6.09
  };

  $scope.total = function(outCurr) {
    return $scope.convertCurrency($scope.qty * $scope.cost, $scope.inCurr, outCurr);        
  };
  $scope.convertCurrency = function(amount, inCurr, outCurr) {
    return amount * $scope.usdToForeignRates[outCurr] / $scope.usdToForeignRates[inCurr];
  };
  $scope.pay = function() {
    window.alert("Thanks!");
  };
  $scope.Resqty = $scope.total($scope.outCurr);   
  });
})(angular);
```

**Updated:**    this ***$scope.Resqty = $scope.total($scope.outCurr);*** doesn't get updated because in this value will be assign only once when loaded. In order to update the value in the textbox you will need to called the function every time on an **event**. Then only it will be updated.

Comment: no I don't get an error. However, with my previous code I get this error: Error: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$scope.total($scope.outCurr)')

Comment: So, do you know how can I resolve that problem ? Here is an example of what I've tried but it doesn't work neither since it doesn't update when I change the value of cost or qty : plnkr.co/edit/hjS20eo4jQRTHx0ZLmS1?p=preview

Comment: Hi @Othmane I have updated the code now and explains why it was not working earliers.. Now u can check this code it's working fine now. Hope this is the one that you have wanted.